# Autoloading não reconhece comando use , depois de um submit?

Tags: php, php-autoload

```js
<?php
namespace App\Controller;


class Action {
    
    function mostrarDado(){
        echo "Mostrando Dados....";
    }
    
}
```

```css
<?php
$paramUser = $_GET['usuario'];
$paramSenha = $_GET['senha'];
var_dump($paramUser);
var_dump($paramSenha);

$act = new App\Controller\Action();
var_dump($act->mostrarDado());

?>
```

```html
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
?>

<html>
<form action="App/Script/Script.php" method="get">
<input name="usuario">
<input name="senha">
<button type="submit"></button>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Olá @alan bem vindo ao StackOverflow, por favor adicione trechos do seu código para que possamos encontrar os problemas.

Comment: Olá @LucasDuete obrigado !!, postei o código acima, estou com essa dúvida com relação a como o php trata submissão de formulaŕios, é certo que eu obtendo o get , post , mas o autoload não carrega a instanciação depois de uma submissão. o Use não faz nada pelo que andei pesquisando, mas o autoload , não reconhece depois de um submit , somente se eu redeclarar no arquivo posterior.  Como faço para que reconheça mesmo depois de submit? sem dar redirect, pelo foward mesmo?

Comment: Estou usando o autoload do composer em um projeto sem framework , somente para testes. Estou fazendo a propagação do autoload , apartir de index.php, depois para script.php e finalmente para action.php, com essa propagação do autoload, sem submit ocorre o reconhecimento normal dos namespaces, logo ao dar um submit apartir do index perde-se a declaração do require para a vendor/autload.php.

Comment: Com submit : console: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Controller\Action

Comment: É correto dizer que o autoload depende exclusivamente do meu index.php, e que toda minha aplicação gira em torno de uma configuração de rota apartir dele ou vinculado a ele ?  porque ao meu entender posso me apoderar da interceptação de requisição para roteamento, mas sem perder meu vínculo com o autoload?